# CSOM Equivalent of allusers

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

Can anyone tell me if there is an Equivalent of allusers in sharepoint csom.  I cant seem to find anything.  Basically im creating a remote event receiver and im trying to replace the following piece of code with the CSOM equivalent

```
properties.Web.AllUsers.GetByID(properties.GroupUserId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe this wasn't answered!

The following should work:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.siteusers.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.usercollection.getbyid.aspx